# google analytics need to automatically export xml for this swf

Tags: xml, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am building a CMS system and wanting to incorporate google analytics reporting relevant for each site.

I have found a quite useful and cool little feature here http://freshwebtrends.com/show-off-your-google-analytics-on-your-site/13/.  However I am wanting this to automatically update. In order for this to work, the xml file has to be downloaded and then replaced in the root folder.

Is there a way I can do this using these files? or is there an alternative out there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. **Technical Solution**.  At the time that article was written, Google had yet to release their Google Analytics API.  In April 2009 Google launched an API providing direct access to Google Analytics data.  Check out this [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html) for more information.  You would be much better off utilizing the API than trying to work off this solution.
2. **Less Technical Solution**.  There have been a number Google Analytics API based apps and webservices developed which simplify "exposing" GA data.  You can find them [here](http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/).

I have developed a serviced called EmbeddedAnalytics which allows you to define charts and then embed them into pages of your site.  It is a very simple process and requires none of the programming required to use the API directly.   The site is: [www.embeddedanalytics.com](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).

More and more we get requests from people having CMS type applications such as yourself.  And they want to provide Admin pages with selected charts of key performance indicators.  This is something we have developed and continue to (although at the current time it is not published on our site).   There are many ways this is accomplished:

- through separate Google Analytics profile for each user of the CMS.
- utilizing a filter on the "PagePath" dimension.
- using a single site-wide GA profile but filtering using a custom variable the CMS has set.

Please contact us through the site if you would like more information on this.